# Operating with datetime types in jess rules

Tags: java, datetime, rules, jess

I am processing ontologies with JessTab. I need to operate with XMLSchema DateTime values e.g. compare dates.

```
(defrule checIntervalStatus 
(declare (salience 40))
(object (is-a http://www.w3.org/2006/time#Instant) 
        (OBJECT ?ie)
        (http://www.w3.org/2006/time#inXSDDateTime ?iet)
)
(object (is-a http://www.w3.org/2006/time#Instant) 
        (OBJECT ?ib)
        (http://www.w3.org/2006/time#inXSDDateTime ?ibt)
)
(object (is-a http://www.w3.org/2006/time#Interval) 
        (OBJECT ?oi)
        (http://www.w3.org/2006/time#hasBeginning ?ib)
        (http://www.w3.org/2006/time#hasEnd ?ie)
)
=>
(if (< ?ibt (slot-get http://.../sample.owl#q11767 http://www.w3.org/2006/time#inXSDDateTime))  
then    
(printout t "The interval " (instance-name ?oi) " has start time " ?ibt " and end time " ?iet crlf)
)
)
```

The following exception appears:

```
Jess reported an error in routine Value.javaObjectValue
while executing (<  ?ibt (slot-get http://.../sample.owl#q11767  http://www.w3.org/2006/time#inXSDDateTime))
while executing (if (< ?ibt  (slot-get http://.../sample.owl#q11767 
http://www.w3.org/2006/time#inXSDDateTime))
then (printout t "The interval "  (instance-name ?oi) " has start time " ?ibt " and end time " ?iet crlf))
while executing defrule MAIN::checkIntervalStatus
while executing (run).
  Message: '"~@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime 2015-04-08T02:54:45.217"' is a list, not  a Java object.
 Program text: ( run )
 at  line 20.
```

I tried to parse the XMLSchema datetime into Java Datetime through:
(new Date (slot-get http://.../sample.owl#q11767 http://www.w3.org/2006/time#inXSDDateTime)) 
but got another exception:

> Message: Constructor not found: (new Date (slot-get
>   http://.../sample.owl#q11767
>   http://www.w3.org/2006/time#inXSDDateTime)).   Program text: ( run ) 
>   at line 22.
>   Nested exception is: java.util.Date

Comment: I suggest that you establish the Java type of `(slot-get  http://.../sample.owl#q11767 http://www.w3.org/2006/time#inXSDDateTime)`. It isn't String; the other error suggests that it is a CLP list. If the list contains a String and if it is formatted properly, it should be able to call the Date constructor.

Comment: The output of: `(slot-get http://.../sample.owl#q11767 http://www.w3.org/2006/time#inXSDDateTime)` is `("~@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime 2015-04-08T02:54:45.217")`

Comment: @laune Seems like `("~@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime 2015-04-08T02:54:45.217")` cannot be parsed into Java datetime type